# How to connect frontend to backed in K8S?

Tags: node.js, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an application that has two k8s deployments called `onboarding-server` and `frontend`
onboarding-server is a node server and frontend is a react application that is built and deployed using Nginx.

Here is a snippet which is returned when I run  `kubectl get all`

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/frontend-deployment-578f898ffb-cc7gc   1/1     Running   0          15s
pod/node-deployment-7f4754fdf5-fnmls       1/1     Running   0          7d10h

NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
service/frontend-service    LoadBalancer   10.100.200.64    10.167.198.105   80:31167/TCP     13d
service/node-service   LoadBalancer   10.100.200.71    10.167.199.136   3200:32276/TCP   13d

NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/frontend-deployment   1/1     1            1           5d12h
deployment.apps/node-deployment       1/1     1            1           7d10h

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/frontend-deployment-578f898ffb   1         1         1       17s
replicaset.apps/node-deployment-7f4754fdf5       1         1         1       7d10h
```

And my `nginx.conf` config looks something like this

```
upstream node-service{
  server node-service;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location = /api {
      proxy_pass http://node-service;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.html;
    location = / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      internal;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Now I try to talk to my backend service from the frontend using this URL

`/api/onboarding/v1/user/login`

My understanding of Nginx is that when I request `/api` it should redirect me to 
`http://node-service/api/onboarding/v1/user/login`
and hence should return the appropriate response.
But what I get back is

```
Fetch failed loading: POST
 http://192.168.5.21/api/onboarding/v1/user/login
```

How can I connect to node-service from Nginx?

EDIT 1 :
One thing that I forgot to mention is that when I go inside the container using the `exec` command I am able to get appropriate response using

```
curl http://192.168.5.21/api/onboarding/v1/user/login
```

Comment: 192.168.5.21 is the ip of the pods or its the ip of nodes?

Answer (score 1):

For path-based routing in Kubernetes, I'll suggest you to take a look at **Ingress**. You can use **Nginx Ingress** for kubernetes in your case. You'll be able to map services based on path.

For Example,

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  annotations: {
    'kubernetes.io/ingress.class': nginx
  }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: demo-backend
          servicePort: 80
```

Now, as you are using nginx as a reverse-proxy, you can expose your backend service as a Type NodePort and use the External IP of your backend service instead of using the service name-

```
location = /api {
  proxy_pass http://external-ip:port;
}
```

Comment: I am using Ingress right now and it works fine, But I don't want to use IP address and neither do I want new Hostname.  I want to know how do I configure Nginx so that I can connect using the service name.

Comment: Well. In that case you can include the containerPort in your proxy_pass as - **proxy_pass http://node-service:3200;** 

Rember to deploy  node-service first, otherwise you will get an upstream not found error while deploying the frontend deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In your FE you can deploy this config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /be-svc/ {
        proxy_pass "http://<be-svc>.<namespace>/";
  }
}
```

After that your `Dockerfile` can be something like this:

```
FROM nginx:1.14

COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY config/nginx/sites-available/api.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

And just put the ingress like usual in front of your FE service. Hope it helps!